# Access Data Context properties from Context Menu

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I try to learn a little bit about how a listboxview combined with context menu works, so I've made the following XAML code:

```
<UserControl>
   ...
     <ListView
                x:Name="level1Lister"
                Grid.Row="1"
                behaviours:AutoScrollListViewBehaviour.ScrollOnNewItem="True"
                ItemsSource="{Binding LogBuffer, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1" />
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2,0" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                                <ContextMenu>
                                    <MenuItem Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ValidateAllCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, FallbackValue=9999999999}" Header="Copy" />
                                </ContextMenu>
                            </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                            <TextBlock Foreground="{Binding Color, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Text="{Binding Message, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
</UserControl>
```

My main problem is that I'm not able to access my "ValidateAllCommand" function, for some reason... I think it has to do with the "RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor ... " part but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "problem" with the `ContextMenu` is that it is not part of the visual tree. The reason is that the `MenuItem` uses a `Popup` to host the content. While the `Popup` itself is part of the visual tree, its Child content is disconnected as it is rendered in a new `Window` instance. We know there can can only be a single `Window` in the tree and this `Window` must be the root.
Since `Binding.RelativeSource` traverses the visual tree, starting within the detached tree of the `Popup`, to find the binding source, the `Bindig` does not resolve.

The `Popup.Child` content inherits the `DataContext` of the `Popup`. In case of the `ContextMenu` it means that the `MenuItem` inherits the `DataContext` from the `ContextMenu` or from the parent of the `ContextMenu`, to be more precise. In your scenario the `DataContext` is the data model of the `ListBoxItem` i.e. the `DataContext` of the `DataTemplate`.

This means, one solution could be to implement the command in the item model.

The second solution is to make use of routed commands. This solution might be more reasonable in your scenario. The routed command/event can cross the boundary between the two trees.

In the following example, I use the [`ApplicationCommands.Copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.applicationcommands?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#properties) command, one of the predefined routed commands. The `MenuItem.Parameter` is bound to the `DataContext`, which is the item data model (inherited from the `ContextMenu`, as mentioned before). This way the command handler can know the data source.
The event handler can be attached to any parent element using the `UIElement.CommandBindings` property. In the example the handler is attached to the `ListBox` element:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<ListBox>
  <ListBox.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static ApplicationCommands.Copy}"
                    Executed="CopyCommand_Executed" />
  </ListBox.CommandBindings>
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DataItem}">
      <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
          <ContextMenu>
      
            <!-- 
              Here we are in a detached visual tree. 
              The DataContext is inherited from the ContextMenu element. 
              The framework allows routed events to cross the boundaries between the trees.
            -->
            <MenuItem Command="{x:Static ApplicationCommands.Copy}"
                      CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                      Header="Copy" />
          </ContextMenu>
        </StackPanel.ContextMenu>

        <TextBlock />
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
private void CopyCommand_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var listBoxItemModel = e.Parameter as LogBufferItem;

  // TODO::Handle Copy command. For example:
  var commandTarget = this.DataContext as ICommandModel;
  commandTarget.ValidateAllCommand.Execute(listBoxItemModel);
}
```

A third, but not recommended solution is to bind the `DataContext` of the `ContextMenu` parent to the context of interest:

```xml
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DataItem}">
      <StackPanel>
        <!-- DataTemplate DataContext -->

        <Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}, Path=DataContext}">

          <!-- ListBox DataContext -->
          <Grid.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
      
              <!-- 
                Here we are in a detached visual tree. 
                The DataContext is inherited from the ContextMenu/Grid element. 
              -->
              <MenuItem Command="{Binding ValidateAllCommand}"
                        Header="Copy" />
            </ContextMenu>
          </Grid.ContextMenu>
        </Grid>

        <!-- DataTemplate DataContext -->
        <TextBlock />
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox
```

Comment: thank you so much, your explanation is a Christmas gift!

Comment: Haha, nice. Merry Christmas!